# Add character in front and at the end of each character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL I want to add `0` in front and `,` at the end of each character.

Example: `A30F1` -> `0A,03,00,0F,01`

I don't want to use cursor if possible.

Thanks!

EIDT:
I apologize for not asking the most appropriate question at the beginning.

In short, I have a table and for each value in the column `name` I have to convert it to the desired format. For example, we have a `#Temp` table:

```
  CREATE TABLE #Temp (id INT, name VARCHAR(25))

  INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (1, 'A30F1'), (2, 'B51R9'), (3, 'L1721')

  SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be to use a Tally to split the string into it's individual characters, and then use concatenation to add the `0` to the start, and `STRING_AGG` to comma delimit the results:

```sql
DECLARE @YourValue varchar(5) = 'A30F1';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (LEN(@YourValue))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --Up to 100 characters, add more cross joins for more characters
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('0',SS.C),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS NewString
FROM (VALUES(@YourValue))V(YourValue)
     CROSS JOIN Tally T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.YourValue,T.I,1)))SS(C);
```

---

It appears this is meant to be against a table, not a single value. This needs, however, very few changes to work against a table:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(LEN(YourColumn)) FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --Up to 100 characters, add more cross joins for more characters
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('0',SS.C),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON LEN(YT.YourColumn) >= T.I
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(YT.YourColumn,T.I,1)))SS(C)
GROUP BY YT.YourColumn;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2e7908725fcf75b2b053713c7bca16b)

Answer (score 2):

**Original answer:**

A recursive CTE and a `STRING_AGG()` call is also an option (SQL Server 2017+ is needed):

```
DECLARE @text varchar(max) = 'A30F1';
WITH rCTE AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS CharacterPosition, SUBSTRING(@text, 1, 1) AS Character
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CharacterPosition + 1, SUBSTRING(@text, CharacterPosition + 1, 1)
    FROM rCTE
    WHERE CharacterPosition < LEN(@text)
)
SELECT STRING_AGG('0' + Character, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CharacterPosition)
FROM rCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Update:**

You need a different statement, if the names are stored in a table, again using recursion and `STRING_AGG()`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (id INT, name VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (1, 'A30F1'), (2, 'B51R9'), (3, 'L1721')
```

Statement:

```
; WITH rCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      t.id AS id,
      LEFT(t.name, 1) AS Character,
      STUFF(t.name, 1, 1, '') AS CharactersRemaining,
      1 AS CharacterPosition
   FROM #Temp t
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
      r.id,
      LEFT(r.CharactersRemaining, 1),
      STUFF(r.CharactersRemaining, 1, 1, ''),
      CharacterPosition + 1
   FROM rCTE r
   WHERE LEN(r.CharactersRemaining) > 0
)
SELECT 
   id, 
   STRING_AGG('0' + Character, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CharacterPosition) AS name
FROM rCTE
GROUP BY id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Result:

```
id name
1  0A,03,00,0F,01
2  0B,05,01,0R,09
3  0L,01,07,02,01
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the simplest possible with a few variables, `WHILE` and `SUBSTRING`

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(20) = 'A30F1', @i INT = 1, @res NVARCHAR(20)

WHILE (@i <= LEN(@var))
BEGIN
    SET @res = @res + '0' + SUBSTRING(@var, @i, 1) + ','
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT LEFT(@res, LEN(@res) - 1) output
```

Check demo on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a6aca6748a2a0ca22b5194f9f91cc49).

Comment: A `WHILE` and `CURSOR` are doing to be just as slow as each other mind.

Comment: @Larnu For his need, I really think that will work very well. His logic is very simple and strings are very short. For complex and long strings you are correct.

Comment: I disagree. There are very few cases for using a `WHILE` in SQL; this isn't one of them. SQL is a set based language, so it excels it set based methods but, as a result, performs quite poorly at iterative ones like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only applying this to English alphabet characters and digits as in your example you could do this.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (id INT, name VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (1, 'A30F1'), (2, 'B51R9'), (3, 'L1721'), (4, 'A')

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(
                 0x00 + CAST(CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS BINARY(50)), CHAR(0), '0,')
        , 3 
        , LEN(name) * 3 - 1)
FROM   #Temp
```

[returns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2d02/2)

```
0A,03,00,0F,01
0B,05,01,0R,09
0L,01,07,02,01
0A
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the binary representation of the `nvarchar` and `varchar` is the same for this limited character set except for padding out with `0x00`

```
'A30F1' -> 0x4133304631
N'A30F1' -> 0x41003300300046003100
```